# How to edit XML via Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I want to remake my code so that it could go through `.each{...}` block every time I run the code.

I have a list in which I put names, then I go through this `list item` by `for  loop  and  if`  certain conditions  will be fullfilled it will update `xml tag`  values.

I am new at Groovy and can't find out why it doesn't go through each block every  time when this condition is `true`?

```
p.runAs[0].text() == "true" && p.start[0].text() == date.toString();
```

What should I change to make this code work like if condition works?
Here is what I have:

```
        def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
        for(int i=0;i<value.size();i++) {
          date = value.get(i).substring(0, 10);
          xml.rm.crossross.details.findAll({ p ->
              p.runAs[0].text() == "true" && p.start[0].text() == date.toString();
          }).each({ p ->
              p.start[0].value = addDays(p.start[0].text())
              p.runAs[0].value = "true"
          })
      }
```

Comment: do you mean your p.runAs[0] contains 'true' or the field exists ?

Comment: no  p.start[0].text()  contains   date

Comment: and   runAs  contains   text true

Comment: what  is  start[0]   i mean   on  which  content  it  points  to?